# error selenium-webdriver@4.5.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 14.20.0". Got "14.17.4"

Tags: node.js, react-native, selenium-webdriver, expo, yarn-v2

I have been having a nightmare with getting my dependencies in order in this branch I have been working in. Today I finally got everything working, and my pipelines in GitLab are now passing. For context, the project is a React Native app using Expo.

So since I got everything working in this branch, I merged this into `develop`. But now, when I try and run `yarn` in my `develop` branch, I get the following error:

```
error selenium-webdriver@4.5.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 14.20.0". Got "14.17.4"
error Found incompatible module.
```

I previously got this error in my other branch, and did as it said, and upgraded my Node to `v14.20.0`, but when I did this, it did more damage than good and caused countless TypeScript problems.

I was having some problems with where my modules were being installed, so used `nohoist` and that seemed to do the trick, and I went back to Node `v14.17.4` and everything seemed to work. But now after merging that branch into `develop`, `develop` no longer works.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "oml",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": ": You are in the project root. cd into the relevant package and run yarn start to start that package.",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "docs": "yarn workspace @oml/types docs",
    "test:commit": "yarn workspaces run test:commit",
    "test:ci": "yarn workspaces run test:ci",
    "check-code": "yarn workspaces run check-code",
    "build:web": "cd apps/trader-portal && expo build:web --non-interactive && rm -rf ../firebase/web-build && mv web-build ../firebase/",
    "build:android": "cd apps/trader-portal && expo build:android -t app-bundle --non-interactive --no-wait --release-channel",
    "build:ios": "cd apps/trader-portal && expo build:ios --non-interactive --no-wait --release-channel"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
    "concurrently": "^6.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.11.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "open-cli": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "2.3.2",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "./packages/*",
      "./apps/**"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/@react-native-community",
      "**/@react-native-community/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I would like to mention, I have no idea why I am getting this error, as I had never heard of `selenium-webdriver` until I got this error. I have no direct reference to it anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 4):

According to some other answers in stackoverflow, you can ignore the error with `yarn add "library name" --ignore-engines`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved this updating the node version 14.20.0 how the error said.

Check the node version between pipeline and local.

Comment: This worked for me, the specific commands I used were `nvm install 14.20.0` followed by `nvm use 14.20.0` and then I reran the upgrade command (which for me was `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest`).  `nvm` is the Node Version Manager (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).